# run javascript code for every div on the page, individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

i have some dynamic data pulled from the DB on my website.

The content will have a number of images that will eventually be output e.g.

```
<img class="buildimage" src="IMAGEURL"></img>
<img class="buildimage" src="IMAGEURL2"></img>
<img class="buildimage" src="IMAGEURL3"></img>
```

All of the image sources are external URL's and can be any size (ratio not file size)

What i want to do is, when the page loads, it checks all divs with the class of buildimage and then checks for their size. If it is above X amount, it changes the class, if not its another class.

This

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var box = $(".blogtest"),
    img = box.find("img.buildimage");
    if (img.width() > 701) {
        $("img.buildimage").attr("class", "buildimage-large");
    } else if (img.width() < 700) {
        $("img.buildimage").attr("class", "buildimage-small");
    }
    })
});
```

Works, but it sets all of the images on the page to the same class. I understand why, but i just dont know how to make this function 'run through' each of the images separately and change their classes.

The image tags are converted from BB to html with this:

```
$text = str_replace("[img]", "<img class='buildimage' src='", "$text");
$text = str_replace("[/img]", "'>", "$text");
```

would be it easier / possible to create a function that would output a class? and then put that inside the  tag. so e.g.

```
$text = str_replace("[img]", "<img class='<script>getImageClass()<.script>' src='", "$text");
```

Or something like that? Not sure on the easiest way around this.

Craig

Comment: I think theres an error here "<img class='<script>getImageClass()<.script>' src='"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you use jQuery. In this case you should use the [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method from jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var box = $(".blogtest");
    box.find("img.buildimage").each(function() {
       var img = $(this), width = img.width();
       if (width >= 700) {
          img.addClass("buildimage-large");
       } else if (width < 700) {
          img.addClass("buildimage-small");
       }
    });
});
```

Here is an example of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/dragulceo/Lqm6a/1/

Comment: thanks for the reply, although no answers seem to be working, i have made jsfiddle here so you can see http://jsfiddle.net/KRwE2/

Comment: Did you check the link I added? You have to use "Inspect element" in the results panel selecting the images. You will notice that the classes are added

Comment: Got it working now, had an error missing a bracket (my mistake) which threw up some errors further down! Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Other answers are wrong because the second parameter in the each callback in not a jQuery object rather a HTMLElement.

Comment: @tavi not **all** of the answers, see BlackSheep's usage of the more specialized [.addClass()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20894782/2770309) method

Comment: Yes, sorry I generalised. Now I noticed some of them fixed the code.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [JQuery "each" function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$.each(box.find("img.buildimage"), function(i, img){
    img = $(img);
    if (img.width() > 701) {
        img.attr("class", "buildimage-large");
    } else if (img.width() < 700) {
        img.attr("class", "buildimage-small");
    }
});
```

Comment: You are calling the `.width()` method on a DOM Element object that doesn't have `.width()` method. Either use `width` property or create a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) callback function which is executed once for each selected element:

```
box.find("img.buildimage").addClass(function() {
   return $(this).width() > 701 
          ? "buildimage-large" 
          : "buildimage-small";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect place for jQuery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".blogtest").find("img.buildimage").each(function(index, img) {
    if (img.width() > 701) {
      img.addClass("buildimage-large");
    } else if (img.width() < 700) {
      img.addClass("buildimage-small");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has an [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method that would be useful. An edit of [rtcherry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20894755/2770309)'s answer:

```
var imageWidthThreshold = 700;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // can combine into one selector statement
  $(".blogtest img.buildimage").each(function(index, img) {

    var image = $(img),
       // get the value and save so as to save time (1 vs 2 invocations)
       imageWidth = image.width();

    if (imageWidth >= imageWidthThreshold ) {
      image.addClass("buildimage-large");
    } else if (imageWidth < imageWidthThreshold ) {
      image.addClass("buildimage-small");
    }

  });
});
```